# What is the word that describes the absence of bureaucracy?

Tags: word-request

What is the word which describes the absence of formless, of long procedure with bureaucrats? I was thinking about formsless but it sounds weird...

Comment: Free-form, or ad-hoc seem to capture some of the idea.

Comment: This isn't really appropriate but for the extreme you could use *anarchy*.

Comment: @amory: It's very odd that bureaucracy is a negative term, and at the same time bureaucracy's antonyms often have a negative connotation as well.

Comment: That... is an excellent observation.  Perhaps most implementations of government are unsatisfactory?  Reminds me of the Churchill quote: "*...democracy is the worst form of government except all those other forms that have been tried..."

Comment: Ordered, well run, well regulated, structured; orderly, efficient, neat, tidy, methodical, organized.

Comment: "formless" is an adjective meaning "without form". "absence of formless" makes no sense. And why mention "formsless", which isn't a word? Maybe that's why it "sounds weird". Maybe you mean "formality" or "formalities?"

Comment: @user814064 Is bureaucracy only repressive that free-form would be opposite of it?

Comment: @Amory "Anarchy" seems nice as it doesn't include state officials. "Democracy" may also be a nice option as it propose public elected individuals rather than state officials.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single antonym for "bureaucratic", because "bureaucratic" encompasses a number of ideas, although I think ***streamlined*** or possibly ***efficient*** is perhaps the closest to what you want in your case.

Other examples that you might want, depending on what aspect of the word "bureaucratic" you are contrasting include:

*easy*, *simple*, *transparent*, *efficient*, *flexible*, *fast*, *direct*, *bespoke*, *personalized*, *streamlined*, *ill-defined*, *unprepared*, *undefined*, *undocumented*, *unaccountable* and *elected*.

Answer (score 1):

How about *[streamlined](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/streamline)*:

> **streamline**, *v*.: to improve a business, organization, process, etc. by making it more
>   modern or simple

Example:

> Freedonia streamlined its archaic visa application bureaucracy,
>   replacing it with a three-question online form.

Comment: Is freedom and flexibility the opposite of bureaucracy? If you think deeply not following a law/rule/convention is also a law/rule/convention.

Answer (score 1):

*Absence of red tape* or *cutting the [red tape](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=red%20tape)* could be used:

> "excessive bureaucratic rigmarole," 1736, in reference to the red tape
>   formerly used in Great Britain (and the American colonies) for binding
>   up legal and other official documents, mentioned from 1690s.

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_tape)

> Red tape is commonly accepted to be a barrier to business,
>   particularly small business. In Canada, the Canadian Federation of
>   Independent Business has done extensive research into the impact of
>   red tape on small businesses.
>
> The European Commission has a competition that offers an award for the
>   "Best Idea for Red Tape Reduction". The competition is "aimed at
>   identifying innovative suggestions for reducing unnecessary
>   bureaucracy stemming from European law".[6] In 2008, the European
>   Commission held a conference entitled 'Cutting Red Tape for Europe'.
>   The goal of the conference was "reducing red tape and overbearing
>   bureaucracy," in order to help "business people and entrepreneurs
>   improve competitiveness".[7]

Answer (score 0):

**Non-bureaucratic** seems to me to be the obvious term to describe the absence of bureaucracy, but it may not be appropriate in all contexts depending exactly how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[laissez-faire](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laissez-faire)*

> a philosophy or practice characterized by a usually deliberate abstention from direction or interference especially with individual freedom of choice and action

Answer (score 0):

**Adhocracy**, or in a positive business context, **bureau-adhocracy**.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what these terms mean. I would guess they are not generally used.

Comment: @user3169 Adhocracy is a flexible, adaptable and informal form of organization that is defined by a lack of formal structure that employs specialized multidisciplinary teams grouped by functions. It operates in an opposite fashion to a bureaucracy. - wiki.

Answer (score 0):

## Freedom

Yeah, I believe 'freedom' is the best answer to your question.

From [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freedom)

> 1 : the quality or state of being free: such as
>
> > a : the absence of necessity, coercion, or constraint in choice or action
> >     b : liberation from slavery or restraint or from the power of another : INDEPENDENCE
> >     c : the quality or state of being exempt or released usually from something onerous,  freedom from care